# Changing a div content twice in one pass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi this is my first question on stackoverflow , and I hope it can help me on my problem.

I have a empty div section on a user control like this :

```
<div id="attachmentlist"></div>
```

this div's content will load in a javascript function named bindattachment()
in this function I used some jquery function to set html and set it to div content like this

```
jQuery("#attachmentlist").html(somegeneratedhtml);
```

it works ok but generating "somegeneratedhtml" takes too long and I want before that div content sets to this generated html, a text like "loading please wait ..." shows in same div . So I used same code to set html before setting div with "somegeneratedhtml" like this

```
jQuery("#attachmentlist").html('<p>loading please wait ...');
```

So bindattachment() will look like this

```
function bindattachment()
{
   jQuery("#attachmentlist").html('<p>loading please wait ...</p>');
   var html;
   html = "somegeneratedhtml";
   jQuery("#attachmentlist").html(html);
}
```

and what I get is a list of attachment links on div but "loading please wait ..." never shows.

I want until html generates on bindattachment "loading please wait ..." phrase shows in div

Comment: `jQuery("#attachmentlist")` -- note the `#`

Comment: sorry I was editing post to match the correct code.

Comment: How are you loading the content that "takes too long"?

Comment: Can you add your code to a jsfiddle?

Comment: there is a foreach loop to generate attachment list , I can not post codes to jsfiddle because it is a commercial project and I haven't rights to do that .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During a JS execution context, the UI is usually only updated after your JS finishes. Therefore, calling

```
jQuery("#attachmentlist").html('<p>Loading, please wait ...</p>');
// long loop here
jQuery("#attachmentlist").html('<p>Finished</p>');
```

Means that the first update to the DOM (calling `.html`) will be ignored since the UI thread never gets run until the JS finishes. There are things you can do in JS that would trigger a layout but it doesn't mean the UI will actually update.

If you want to make sure the first message displays, you should update it, then run your code to generate the HTML asynchronously. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/QZrSu/4/),

```
var div = $('#attachmentlist');
// This will never display because the HTML is overwritten before the UI thread
// runs
div.html('<p>First call to set html, will not display');
// This will display because there are no other synchronous calls to update the same
// DOM elemements
div.html("second call to set html, this displays");
// The function passed to setTimeout runs after the UI has had a chance to update
setTimeout(function() {
    // Long running script
    var html = "";
    for (var i=0; i < 100000; i ++) {
        html+= "testing...<br/>";
    }
    // By updating the HTML with a timeout, the previous call to $.html
    // will be visible on the screen for a minimum amount of time
    div.html(html);
}, 1);
```

**Note on Long Running Scripts**

Note that if generating the HTML with JS is taking a long time, it could lock up the browser, and you should use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) to generate the HTML asynchronously, that is, it wouldn't lock up the UI as JS running under the normal JS thread would.

Comment: @JasonSperske True, as long as you understand that I'm explaining a different concept, not how to improve jQuery performance. I'd rather keep the code as close to how the OP had it.

Comment: makes sense.  I was almost done with my answer when you posted yours, this was an attempt as making at least some use of the fiddle I had created :)

Comment: @JasonSperske I think this JSFiddle captures what the OP would like to do, based on your initial JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QZrSu/4/

Comment: @JuanMendes I think this is my answer , and I will tick it as soon as I test it in my project thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you have to use

```
jQuery("#attachmentlist").html('<p>loading please wait ...</p>');
```

to add your text in a div with the id attachmentlist.

Ok, you already corrected it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that it takes that long to load but I would guess that what's happening is loading please wait is quickly replaced in `jQuery("attachmentlist").html(somegeneratedhtml);`. What I would do is create two `div`s inside attachmentlist. Have one contain the loading message and the other will be for the generated html. Use `.hide()` and `.show()` to choose which is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wndW/) with your code.  I added a simple `$(document).ready()` function to run the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   bindattachment(); 
});

function bindattachment()
{
   jQuery("#attachmentlist").html('<p>loading please wait ...</p>');
   var html;
   html = "somegeneratedhtml";
   jQuery("#attachmentlist").html(html);
}
```

The `div` shows the correct 'somegeneratedhtml'.

It would be helpful to see what is generating 'somegeneratedhtml'.  The error might be happening within that function.

Comment: I'd also use the '$' in front rather than jQuery as it is accepted as best practice.

Comment: Best practice is to use `jQuery` to avoid naming conflicts. If you want to use `$`, you should do `(function($){})(jQuery)`.

Answer (score -1):

The time it is taking is not to change the html inside the div, it is to render your html.

Comment: -1 The time it takes is to generate the HTML, as the OP mentioned in the question. You've misunderstood the question. The question is why is the first update not visible if there's a number of seconds between the two calls to `$.html`